# React native navigation mode prop usage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I was looking at react navigation 5 docs and saw the example where you learn to make a full screen modal.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal

In the example above they use a root stack navigator with a nested stack navigator and a screen named Modal, our screen modal, but for some reason mode="modal" prop is used in root stack navigator instead of ModalScreen component (our modal will go from bottom to top as it should, mode prop achieves this) but why is it not used in ModalScreen but in RoosStackNavigator

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator();
const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

function RootStackScreen() {
  return (
    <RootStack.Navigator mode="modal">
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={MainStackScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen name="MyModal" component={ModalScreen} />
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  );
}


function MainStackScreen() {
  return (
    <MainStack.Navigator>
      <MainStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: Navigator determines the transition type, not the screens, if you want a custom type of transition, you should define that in navigator level. That's why RootStack is defined and every screen inside that will follow modal transitions

Comment: yes, every screen inside root satck will have modal transitions, included the ones in the stack navigator when I only want the modals to have that kind of transition...